# Javascript regular expressions for Query Builder

Tags: javascript

This may have been asked in the past but I couldnt find a suitable answer. What I am looking for is a method to extract parameters from an sql query such as below. The queries will always be an EXEC statement followed by the query name, and possible parameters.

Here is an example of what I may recieve

```
EXEC [dbo].[myProcedure] @Param1
```

This could also be as follows

```
EXEC [dbo].[myProcedure] @Param1, @Param2, @Param3
```

Those are the only types of queries that the input will take. As for why I am doing this, well thats another question all together, and I am pretty set on going down this route.

What I am looking for is to be able to take the above strings and produce an array of values such as

```
['@Param1','@Param2','@Param3',....]
```

I originally tried to just parese using a simple while statement but I seem to have huge issues there.

I hope this question makes sense,

Cheers,

Nico

**[Edit]**

Sorted this by using the following statement

```
function eParams(e) {
    var i = e.indexOf('@');
    if (i <= 0)
        return;
    e = e.substring(i);
    var p = e.split(',');
    var eList = [];
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0, j = p.length - 1; i <= j; i++) {
        var sP = p[i].trim();
        if (sP.indexOf('@') < 0)
            continue;
        eList.push(sP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'EXEC [dbo].[myProcedure] @Param1, @Param2, @Param3';
(str).match(/(@[^\s,]+)/g);
```

will return an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "EXEC [dbo].[myProcedure] @Param1, @Param2, @Param3";
var i = s.indexOf('@');
var a = s.substr(i).split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

(error checking omitted)

Comment: fails here: EXEC [dbo].[myProcedure] `@Param1` , `@Param2` , `@Param3`
Whitespaces...